How do I update a bool value of a many to many relation collection in Strapi?
I have this Next.js app where I'm using Strapi as a CMS
In Strapi I have a collection called Events
the Event content type has a field which is a relation many to many with the collection Checklist
the Checklist collection has items in it like:
{
  Title: flyers (text),
  Ok: false (boolean)
}

where each item is just a Title and boolean value
so that for each Event frontend I have a checklist of names with a checkbox, like:
☐ flyers
☐ merch
☐ emails

how do I update the boolean value via Strapi put api call? documentation in this sense is non existent
it says you need to use the item id, thanks, that's a 10% of the job here, anyone had this done before perhaps?
in my Next.js api file right now I was trying something like this (where 3 is the ID of the Event and 3 is the ID of the Checklist item):
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import axios from 'axios'

const strapiUrl = process.env.STRAPI_BASE_URL

export async function POST(req) {
    const { isChecked } = req.body;

    try {

        await axios.put(`${strapiUrl}/api/checklist/3/3/Ok`, {
            isChecked,
        });
        
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: `ok`
        },{status: 250});

    }catch (error){
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: `Probable error`
        });
    }
    
}

but I'm working blindly here, it doesn't work and I have no idea why or how should it be to be honest, nowhere in their documentation to be found
